# Вопрос по формам в Django

Tags: python, django

Решил добавить возможность ставить лайки статьям в блоге POST методом.

**models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    article_text = models.TextField()
    article_likes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

**like_form.html**

```
<form action="/article/like/{{ article.id }}/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input hidden name="like" value="+">
    <input type="submit" value="+">
</form>
<p>Рэйтинг: {{ article.article_likes }}</p>
<form action="/article/like/{{ article.id }}/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input hidden name="like" value="-">
    <input type="submit" value="-">
</form>
```

**forms.py**

```
class LikeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['article_likes']
```

**views.py**

```
class Add_like(UpdateView):
    model = Article
    success_url = '/'
    form_class = LikeForm

    def get_object(self):
        object = super(Add_like, self).get_object()
        object.article_likes += 1
        object.save()
        return object
```

Используя метод get_object можно взять объект согласно pk и добавить ему 1. но как реализовать условие`if '+' like+=1 else like-=1` в этом методе ведь он не принимает form.

Comment: Так форма ваша где? Она же принимает сабмит, а не модель

Comment: @BOPOH я новичок в django и несовсем вас понял.
вы имели в ввиду forms.py? добавил его в вопрос.

Comment: `views.py` еще надо

Comment: @BOPOH добавил views.py только он не совсем рабочий

Comment: сам новичок, у меня `views.py` - это функции, которые вызываются на request, например, `def new_list(request): form = ItemForm(data=request.POST)...`. Соответственно, лайк можно было бы получить из `request` во вьюхе, или `form.cleaned_data['like']` из формы. Как сделано у вас вижу впервые, поэтому подождем тех, кто хорошо знаком с django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция которая решает поставленную задачу.

```
def liking(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.__getitem__('like') =='+':
            article = Article.objects.get(id=pk)
            article.article_likes += 1
            article.save()
        else:
            article = Article.objects.get(id=pk)
            article.article_likes -= 1
            article.save()
    return redirect('/article/%s' % pk)
```

Как подсказали опытные специалисты с форума djbook.ru это тот самый редкий случай когда FBV подходит лучше.

Answer (score 0):

`views.py` у Вас не работает, потому что не проходит валидация формы (тип поля Integer, а Вы ему Char подсовываете).

Думаю так должно сработать, но само это решение мне кажется неправильным, потому что например, счетчик лайков может накручивать и скручивать сколько угодно раз один и тот же человек (добавляйте хотя бы cookie при лайке, потом проверяйте нет ли на данном клиенте её.)

**like_form.html**

```
<form action="/article/like/{{ article.id }}/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input hidden type="number" name="like" value="{{ article.article_likes|add:'1' }}">
    <input type="submit" value="+">
</form>

<p>Рэйтинг: {{ article.article_likes }}</p>

<form action="/article/like/{{ article.id }}/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input hidden type="number" name="like" value="{{ article.article_likes|add:'-1' }}">
    <input type="submit" value="-">
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
class AddLike(UpdateView):
    model = Article
    success_url = '/'
    fields = ['article_likes']
    template_name = 'path/to/like_form.html'
```

Другой реализации я в данном решении не вижу.

***В приведенном мною решении, `LikeForm()` не нужна.***

**P.S.** *Я сам не так давно работаю с Django, и на роль эксперта не претендую, буду рад если более опытные товарищи подскажут что-то более интересное для приведенного Вами решения*

Comment: Прошу прощения что привел вас в заблуждение. Данный пример сугубо учебный и был придуман мною для изучения некоторых аспектов фреймворка. 
Мне нравится ваш метод. Я в самом начале изучения и еще не успел прочитать про тэг `"add"`.

Comment: Ничего страшного, все мы с чего то начинаем)